# Unable to solve sporadic split records issue

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-2.7

The raw data coming out of my CRM sporadically delivers a record split over 2 rows within the csv file.

[Raw data from CRM](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Xohce.png):

[image: Raw data from CRM]

The code prepares the data for uploading into my accounting system, in the required format.

Sadly I have been unable to find the code or commands needed to either solve this issue whilst importing, or once imported.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

```
# importing csv module 
import csv

# csv file name
filename = "Sales Document Data-0.csv"

# initializing the titles and rows list
fields = []
rows = []

# reading csv file
with open(filename, 'r') as csvfile:
# creating a csv reader object
csvreader = csv.reader(csvfile)
fields= next(csvreader)
header= list(fields)

# inserting missing header fields
header.insert(1,'EmailAddress')
header.insert(2,'POAddressLine1')
header.insert(3,'POAddressLine2')
header.insert(4,'POAddressLine3')
header.insert(5,'POAddressLine4')
header.insert(6,'POCity')
header.insert(7,'PORegion')
header.insert(8,'POPostalCode')
header.insert(9,'POCounty')
header.insert(15,'InventoryItemCode')
header.insert(23,'TrackingName1')
header.insert(24,'TrackingOption1')
header.insert(25,'TrackingName2')
header.insert(26,'TrackingOption2')
header.insert(28,'InvoicesBrandingTheme')

# remove headers related to description building
header.pop(-1)
header.pop(-1)
header.pop(-1)
#print(header)

# create empty csv file
with open("InvUpload.csv", "w", newline='') as InvUpload:
    #pass
    writer = csv.writer(InvUpload, delimiter=',', quoting=csv.QUOTE_MINIMAL)
    writer.writerow(header)

    # extracting field names through first row
#fields = next(csvreader)
#print(fields)
# extracting each data row one by one
for row in csvreader:
    rows= list(row)
    rows.insert(1,'')
    rows.insert(2,'')
    rows.insert(3,'')
    rows.insert(4,'')
    rows.insert(5,'')
    rows.insert(6,'')
    rows.insert(7,'')
    rows.insert(8,'')
    rows.insert(9,'')
    rows.insert(15,'')
    rows.insert(23,'')
    rows.insert(24,'')
    rows.insert(25,'')
    rows.insert(26,'')
    rows.insert(28,'BPMT')
    # change description, if 'Standard daily rate'

    ts = rows[30]

    try:
        if rows.index('Standard daily rate'):
            rows[16] = (rows[31]+': '+ts.removesuffix('.pdf'))
        else:
            rows.split('\n')
    except:
        pass
    try:
        if rows.index('Base pay rate'):
            rows[16] = (rows[31]+': '+ts.removesuffix('.pdf'))
        else:
            rows.split('\n')
    except:
        pass
    try:
        if rows.index('Hours not applied'):
            rows[16] = (rows[31]+': '+ts.removesuffix('.pdf'))
        else:
            rows.split('\n')
    except:
        pass
    try:
        if rows.index('Unnamed'):
            rows[16] = (rows[31]+': '+ts.removesuffix('.pdf'))
        else:
            rows.split('\n')
    except:
        pass

    # remove data related to description building
    rows.pop(-1)
    rows.pop(-1)
    rows.pop(-1)
    # chnage TaxType to Xero format
    try:
        if rows.index('20.0%'):
            rows[21] = ('20% (VAT on Income)')
        else:
            rows[21] = ('No VAT')
    except:
        pass
    #print(rows)
    # append to previously created csv file
    if rows[14] == '0.00':
        pass
    else:
        with open("InvUpload.csv", "a", newline='') as InvUpload:
            writer = csv.writer(InvUpload, delimiter=',',
                        quotechar='|')
            writer.writerow(rows)
    # message to show file creation
print('File InvUpload.csv has been created')
```

Comment: Could you show what kind of output you would like, and what output you are getting?

Answer (score 0):

try pandas to handle and build a csv that will give you less headaches in the future. But in this case, you should read line by line, and if you haven't found a complementary quote, you should append the next row. Since you are opening a file to read, it will be easy to check if a quote is missing.

Sorry if I didn't help you too much, but I'm not understanding the correlation between the data file (Raw data) and your code. Can you split some code into functions? Will be more easy to visualize your code

Comment: Not used Pada to this point, but have heard and read a little, so will take a look. I will also look at the read line by line and the appending of. Very much appreciate you taking the time and very appreciative of your answer